# Irreducibility of $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

How can I see that the polynomial $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$?

I can't apply eisenstein's theorem. What are the other possibilities?

Comment: Use the geometric summation formula to put it in a different form and see what you can do about that.

Comment: Call the polynomial $p(x)$, calculate $p(x+1)$. Can you apply Eisenstein's theorem to $p(x+1)$?

Comment: @Alizter I can write it as: $\frac{x^5-1}{x-1}$ how does this help?

Answer (score 4):

You can actually apply Eisenstein criterion the polynomial $(x+1)^4+(x+1)^3+(x+1)^2+(x+1)+1=x^4+5x^3+10x^2+10x+5$.

This yields irreducibility of the original polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

It's the fifth cyclotomic polynomial. All cyclotomic polynomials are irreducible over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: *All [cyclotomic polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial) are irreducible over* **Q** - No, they're not.

Comment: Lucian: sure they are.

Comment: Not all polynomials of the form $\dfrac{x^n-1}{x-1}$ are irreducible over **Q**.

Comment: @Lucian what's your counter-example then ?

Comment: @Lucian For $n$ composite, $\frac{x^n - 1}{x-1}$ is not a cyclotomic polynomial.